# face detection and recognition

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, face-recognition, matlab-cvst

my final project in my computer vision course is face recognition.I present the picture to Matlab and it gives me back the name of the person. of course I have previous images of the faces I am searching for in new pictures.
Do you suggest any references and algorithms ?

Answer (score 2):

Convert the image to an array vector, and all the images from training set will form a large M X N matrix where M is the image pixel size and N is the sample number. Two methods are most often used:(1) Principal Component Analysis is used on the matrix to extract the core components, and project them onto a sub-space. (2) Linear Discriminant Analysis is applied to maximize the ratio of the determinant of Inter-class scatter and intra-class scatter. Read [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5455604) for reference.

Answer (score 2):

For face detection you can use the Viola & Jones algorithm.

For classification:

Training:
1. Crop the faces from the image and divide them into blocks.
2. Extract uniform LBP histograms from each block and concatenate the histograms.
3. Feed those LBP features into an SVM.

Testing:
1+2 from Training on the new image, then feed the LBP features to the trained SVM.

You can add an additional step of aligning the images which can boost your performance.

To do that, you can detect facial keypoints (eyes, nose, chin), find a homography between the images you want to align to a frontal image and then apply the homography on the images.

Viola and Jones is implemented in Matlab's computer vision toolbox, I can send you Matlab code of LBP if you'd like and also examples on how to align images. For and SVM package, you can use LibSVM.